# Add avatar image to the joomla profiles - joomla 3.5.1

Tags: php, windows, joomla, profile, avatar

I am trying to add an Avatar photo to jommla profile by follwing this steps
1- my server options
PHP Built On    Windows NT ******* 6.1 build 7600 (Windows 7 Home Premium     Edition) i586
Database Version    5.5.5-10.1.10-MariaDB
Database Collation  utf8_general_ci
Database Connection Collation   utf8mb4_general_ci
PHP Version 5.6.19
Web Server  Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.19
WebServer to PHP Interface  apache2handler
Joomla! Version Joomla! 3.5.1 Stable [ Unicorn ] 05-April-2016 22:45 GMT
Joomla! Platform Version    Joomla Platform 13.1.0 Stable [ Curiosity ] 24-Apr-2013 00:00 GMT
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36

2- Relevant PHP Settings

Safe Mode   Off
Open basedir    None
Display Errors  Off
Short Open Tags Off
File Uploads    On
Magic Quotes    Off
Register Globals    Off
Output Buffering    Off
Session Save Path   C:\xampp\tmp
Session Auto Start  0
XML Enabled Yes
Zlib Enabled    Yes
Native ZIP Enabled  Yes
Disabled Functions  None
Multibyte String (mbstring) Enabled Yes
Iconv Available Yes
Maximum Input Variables 1000

3- files and fields editing

I added the file upload field in the file in

joomla_path/plugins/user/profile/profile.xml

I added this filed to joomla user profile plugin in back-end in the head of form

```
<field name="register-require_avatar"
type="list"
description="PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_AVATAR_DESC"
label="PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_AVATAR_LABEL"
>
<option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
<option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
<option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
</field>
```

I added the (multipart/form-data) to the form.
I added the file upload field in the file in

joomla_path/plugins/user/profile/profiles/profile.xml
I added this filed to joomla user profile plugin in back-end in the head of form

```
<field
            name="avatar"
            type="file"
            id="avatar"
            description="PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_AVATAR_DESC"
            label="PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_AVATAR_LABEL"
        />
```

In the file profile.php which is in the path:
            joomla_path/plugins/user/profile/profile.php

I added this code to create user avatar folder and the code to upload the image file (I added this code in "onUserBeforeSave" Function)

```
import joomla's filesystem classes
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
    // Get the user info
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    //The right way to create user folder and avatar folder
    $path = JPATH_SITE . '/images/users/'. $user->id . '-' . $user->username . '/avatar';
    JFolder::create($path);

    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
    $file = JRequest::getVar('jform', null, 'files', 'array');
    if (isset($file) && $file['size']['profile']['avatar'] != '') {
        //Clean up filename to get rid of strange characters like spaces etc
        $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);

        //First check if the file has the right extension, we need jpg only
        if ($file['type']['profile']['avatar'] == 'image/jpeg' || $file['type']['profile']['avatar'] == 'image/png' || $file['type']['profile']['avatar'] == 'image/gif') {
            if ($file['type']['profile']['avatar'] == 'image/png') {

                $image = imagecreatefrompng($file['tmp_name']['profile']['avatar']);
                imagejpeg($image, $path . '/avatar' . $filename .'.jpg', 80);
                imagedestroy($image);
                $image = JUri::root() . '/images/users/'. $user->id . '-' . $user->username . '/avatar/' . $filename;
            } else if ($file['type']['profile']['avatar'] == 'image/jpeg') {
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']['profile']['avatar']);
                imagejpeg($image, $path . '/avatar' . $filename .'.jpg', 80);
                imagedestroy($image);
            } else if ($file['type']['profile']['avatar'] == 'image/gif') {
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($file['tmp_name']['profile']['avatar']);
                imagejpeg($image, $path . '/avatar' . $filename . '.jpg', 80);
                imagedestroy($image);
            }
        } else {
            //Redirect and notify user file is not right extension
            throw new Exception(JText::_('PLG_USER_FILE_TYPE_INVALID'));

        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

****** the problem is that i cant render the field in database to save the avatar file path ****
must know that i can create the users's avatar folder and i can upload the image file to this path but the problem is how to save the file image's path in database then i can call it in any page by linking to this path so how is the right way to do this ???

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to insert image into database

```
function insertAvatar($userid, $filename, $ext){

// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
try {
// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Insert columns.
$columns = array('user_id', 'profile_key', 'profile_value', 'ordering');

// Insert values.
$values = array($userid,'profile.avatar', $filename.$ext, 1);

// Prepare the insert query.
$query
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
    ->values(implode(',', $values));

$db->setQuery($query);
return $db->execute();
}
catch (Exception $e){
    return $e->getMessage();
}
}
```

Call the function at the appropriate place

```
if ($file['type']['profile']['avatar'] == 'image/png') {
   $this->insertAvatar($user->id, $filename, 'png');
```

Similarly for rest of the three types i.e "jpg" and "gif" use

```
$this->insertAvatar($user->id, $filename, 'jpg');
```

and

```
$this->insertAvatar($user->id, $filename, 'gif');
```

. you call other profile params the same way you can call image filename.

Comment: thanks a lot for you response, but still have problem to organize the code, I inserted the (insertAvatar) function just before the (onUserBeforeSave) and i modified the upload code but nothing append in the data base, just i have a note that the field (file) did not appears in form array in joomla debug like the other fields in array. ah .. other thing about the option required so if the field (avatar) is required in plugin setting page i get the error field required.

Comment: i will add it in new answer

Comment: where is the function? Where have you used it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the function that you created for me

```
function insertAvatar($userid, $filename, $ext){

    // Get a db connection.
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    try {
        // Create a new query object.
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        // Insert columns.
        $columns = array('user_id', 'profile_key', 'profile_value', 'ordering');

        // Insert values.
        $values = array($userid,'profile.avatar', $filename.$ext, 1);

        // Prepare the insert query.
        $query
            ->insert($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'))
            ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
            ->values(implode(',', $values));

        $db->setQuery($query);
        return $db->execute();
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

and this is the function (onUserBeforeSave) where i put my code

```
public function onUserBeforeSave($user, $isnew, $data)
{
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // import joomla's filesystem classes
    jimport('joomla.filesystem.folder');
    // Get the user info
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    //The right way to create user folder and avatar folder
    $path = JPATH_SITE . '/images/users/'. $user->id . '-' . $user->username . '/avatar/';
    JFolder::create($path);

    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
    $file = JRequest::getVar('jform', null, 'files', 'array');
    if (isset($file) && $file['size']['profile']['avatar'] != 0) {
        //Clean up filename to get rid of strange characters like spaces etc
        $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);

        //First check if the file has the right extension, we need jpg only
        if ($file['type']['profile']['avatar'] == 'image/jpeg' || $file['type']['profile']['avatar'] == 'image/png' || $file['type']['profile']['avatar'] == 'image/gif') {
            if ($file['type']['profile']['avatar'] == 'image/png') {

                $image = imagecreatefrompng($file['tmp_name']['profile']['avatar']);
                imagejpeg($image, $path . $filename .'.jpg', 80);
                $this->insertAvatar($user->id, $filename, 'jpg');
                imagedestroy($image);

            } else if ($file['type']['profile']['avatar'] == 'image/jpeg') {
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']['profile']['avatar']);
                imagejpeg($image, $path . $filename .'.jpg', 80);
                $this->insertAvatar($user->id, $filename, 'jpg');
                imagedestroy($image);

            } else if ($file['type']['profile']['avatar'] == 'image/gif') {
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($file['tmp_name']['profile']['avatar']);
                imagejpeg($image, $path . $filename . '.jpg', 80);
                $this->insertAvatar($user->id, $filename, 'jpg');
                imagedestroy($image);
            }
        } else {
            //Redirect and notify user file is not right extension
            throw new Exception(JText::_('PLG_USER_FILE_TYPE_INVALID'));

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Check that the date is valid.
    if (!empty($data['profile']['dob']))
    {
        try
        {
            $date = new JDate($data['profile']['dob']);
            $this->date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            // Throw an exception if date is not valid.
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(JText::_('PLG_USER_PROFILE_ERROR_INVALID_DOB'));
        }
        if (JDate::getInstance('now') < $date)
        {
            // Throw an exception if dob is greather than now.
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(JText::_('PLG_USER_PROFILE_ERROR_INVALID_DOB'));
        }
    }
    // Check that the tos is checked if required ie only in registration from frontend.
    $task       = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('task');
    $option     = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('option');
    $tosarticle = $this->params->get('register_tos_article');
    $tosenabled = ($this->params->get('register-require_tos', 0) == 2) ? true : false;
    if (($task == 'register') && ($tosenabled) && ($tosarticle) && ($option == 'com_user'))
    {
        // Check that the tos is checked.
        if ((!($data['profile']['tos'])))
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(JText::_('PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_TOS_DESC_SITE'));
        }
    }


    return true;
}
```

my code who is between the comments line like this
/////////////////////////////////////

Comment: this is all the code - the function that you create for me and (onUserBeforeSave) function